# How to limit logging frequency?

Tags: java, logging, delay

Does any logging library contain any means to limit logging message frequency?

I mean suppose I have a waiting loop and it logs "Nothing done". How to make next "Nothing done" message would logged only after say 1 second?

I know I can program it myself.

Comment: Do you mean that if the logger receives 50 "Nothing done" within 1 second, only one "Nothing done" would get logged? Or the 50 would get logged but in one go after 1 second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manage this in your code, or you need to write a custom appender (this depends on the logging library you are using)

Answer (score 4):

Most logging libraries support filters to limit logging frequency.

1. See this answer on [SLF4J or Log4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465002/can-i-make-log4j-suppress-logging-specific-messages-for-a-time).
2. See this answer on [`java.util.logging`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986548/how-to-regulate-the-amount-of-printouts-generated-by-a-logging-instruction-produ).